# How to update a ComboBox when is bind to ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I'm new in WPF and I'm trying to bind a ComboBox with an ObservableCollection.
Bing is showing correct values,and when I try to add new values from same page combobox is updated. When I'm trying to add to collection one new item from another PageTest combobox doesn't  show new values , only old ones. What I am doing wrong?
Here is my first ComboTest window with ComboBox.

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollection}" Width="200" Height="50">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BuildingType.A, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BuildingType.B, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BuildingType.C, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Width="100" Height="100"> To next page</Button>
    </Grid>
```

Code behind for this window :

```
   public partial class ComboTest : Page
    { 
        ComboViewModel temp = new ComboViewModel();
        public ComboTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = temp;
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {          
           NavigationService.Navigate(new PageTest(temp));
        }
    }
```

Here is my view model:

```
    public class ComboViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Building> ObservableCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Building>()
        {
            new Building()
            {
                Price = "250",
                BuildingType = new BuildingType() {A = "BuildingTypeA", B = "BuildingTypeA", C = "BuildingTypeA"}
            },
            new Building()
            {
                Price = "250",
                BuildingType = new BuildingType() {A = "BuildingTypeB", B = "BuildingTypeB", C = "BuildingTypeB"}
            },
            new Building()
            {
                Price = "250",
                BuildingType = new BuildingType() {A = "BuildingTypeC", B = "BuildingTypeC", C = "BuildingTypeC"}
            }
        };

        public  void AddItem()
        {
            ObservableCollection.Add(new Building()
            {
                Price = "250",
                BuildingType = new BuildingType() { A = "BuildingTypeC", B = "BuildingTypeC", C = "BuildingTypeC" }
            });
        }
    }
```

And another page:

```
  <Grid>
        <Button Width="200" Height="100" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Add and Navigate Back</Button>
   </Grid>
```

And code for this page

```
 public partial class PageTest : Page
    {
        private ComboViewModel temp;
        //public PageTest()
        //{
        //    InitializeComponent();
        //}

        public PageTest(ComboViewModel comboViewModel)
        {
            temp = comboViewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            temp.AddItem();
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should pass the same instance "temp" of ComboViewModel that is created in ComboTest to PageTest. In PageTest on button click you are creating new instance of ComboViewModel hence newly added items dont't show up.

Comment: I try as you suggest and didn't work as expected. I create in PageTest constructor that recive ComboViewModel a reference. and with that reference I call AddItem();

Comment: can you edit the post with have you tried. Also r u caching the instance of comboTest and render the same page on navigation back?

Comment: Edited . When I modify collection as static it work just fine. But with passing instance , don't.

Comment: Currently when you navigate back, a new instance of combotest page is created instead of reusing the page. Hence you are losing changes made to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate back a new instance of combotest is created, hence changes made to collection are lost.

one way of achieving the same is setting the keepalive property of the root page (combotest).

```
KeepAlive="True"
```

check this [navigation-overview#PageLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview#PageLifetime)